# What's the linguistics term for "Schubertiaden" and similar words?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, linguistics

What's the linguistics term for "Schubertiaden" and similar words (that refers to a group of people based on a person's name)?

"Schubertiaden" refers to the group of people of similar interest and activity with musician Schubert.　What are some other examples?

Comment: Other examples of what? Group names or linguistics terms for group names?

Comment: I doubt there's an existing word, but **icononym** would be a reasonable neologism. Ignore those few people trying to establish this as a *"word for words where the first letter is suggestive of the meaning, such as 'Wavy'"*. Stick to your guns and say its a *"collective term for words identifying people by their favourite cultural icon"*.

Comment: A Schubertiade is a festival with the music of Schubert as its central theme: it's not a person, as far as I know. It's just a festival named after an artist, no doubt a variation on "Olympiade".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia *[-onym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-onym)* article presents dozens of name-related words ending with *onym*, none of which exactly apply to your question.  (An *[eponym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym)*, for example, is "the name of a person or thing, whether real or fictitious, after which a particular place, tribe, era, discovery, or other item is named or thought to be named", while a *[demonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym)* is "a name for a resident of a locality ... [frequently] derived from the name of the locality".  Unfortunately *icononym* is not listed in the article.)

A hypernym of the word you seek is *taxonym*, "a name used for classification or identification purposes", but for better specificity the term *groupname* seems appropriate.  For example, in
[1912-1925](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22groupname%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1500,cd_max:1925&lr=lang_en) it was used in sentences like the following, where its meaning is *name of a group*:

> Judging from the reports of ... expeditions, they must have heard while there the native groupname Hasinai;

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a type of eponym.

Comment: No; an [eponym](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponym) _gives_ the name. _Schubert_ is the eponym; a Schubertiade is an _eponymous_ event named in Schubert's honor.